# Blender Geonodes - Move colliding Vertices outside of object?

Tags: simulation-nodes

So, I have something like this already:

[image]

And these are my nodes:

[image]

My question is: Is there a better way of doing this? Like the offset automatically changing depending on the sphere's speed? Or maybe to move the vertex outside of the sphere with each frame? Kind of like a reverse shrinkwrap. I want to animate the sphere crushing the square is what I want to do while using geonodes.